# Is there a way to do this with Auto Properties?

Tags: c#, properties

I have code that looks something like this:

```
Card m_currentCard;
public Card CurrentCard {
    get { return m_currentCard; }
    set {
        m_currentCard = value;
        QuestionLabel.Text = CurrentCard.Question;
    }
}
```

It doesn't do anything special in terms of getting and setting the value of the property, but it does something additional when setting the property. Am I stuck using a separate variable, or is there a way to do this with auto properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do that using automatically implemented properties.